# Having trouble in understanding the syntax of a overloaded class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I am having problem in understanding one line from the the following code snippet (taken from the book: MCSD Certification Toolkit (Exam 70-483) Programming in C#)...
Here the problem set is given as:

Make an Ellipse class that represents an ellipse. It should store the ellipse’s size and position in a Location property of type RectangleF (defined in the System.Drawing namespace). Give it two constructors: one that takes a RectangleF as a parameter and one that takes X position, Y position, width,
and height as parameters. Make the second constructor invoke the first, and make the constructors throw an exception if width or height is less than or equal to 0.

```
class Ellipse
{
    public RectangleF Location { get; set; }

    // Constructor that takes a RectangleF as a parameter.
    public Ellipse(RectangleF rect)
    {
         // Validate width and height.
        if (rect.Width <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width", "Ellipse width must be greater than 0.");

        if (rect.Height <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("height", "Ellipse height must be greater than 0.");

        // Save the location.
        Location = rect;
    }

   // Constructor that takes x, y, width, and height as parameters.
   public Ellipse(float x, float y, float width, float height)
       : this(new RectangleF(x, y, width, height))
   {
   }
}
```

I am having problem in understanding the following line... 
Could anyone explain what the following line does? Please be a little elaborate in your explanation!

```
:this(new RectangleF(x, y, width, height))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:this(new RectangleF(x, y, width, height))` calls the `public Ellipse(RectangleF rect)` constructor. Basically your Ellipse is either constructed out of `x, y, width and height` or from a `rectangle`. And when you construct it from `x, y, width and height`, you are passing them as parameters for constructing a `rectangle`, which is passed on as a parameter to your other constructor. At the end, you are only using one constructor - the one that accepts a `rectangle`, the other one just 'redirects' you to it (transforming rectangle parameters, into a rectangle)

Comment: So that you don't have to duplicate the logic of your other constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**What it does**

The line in question creates a new instance of `RectangleF` using the parameters supplied to the contructor. Then it initialisizes the instance of `Ellipse` with the created `RectanlgeF` using the first constructor.

**Why is this useful**

There is quite a lot of logic in initializing an `Ellipse`. One could have initialized it in the same way it was done in the first construtor, but this would mean duplication of the logic - with all the bad that comes with it. This way you have have a single place of resposibility for initializing a new `Ellipse` but multiple ways you can create such an instance.

Consider creating a new instance of an `Ellipse` in a place where you have a `RectangleF` available and only the first contructor for `Ellipse` is implemented. You would have to 'deconstruct' the rectangle by calling

```c#
var ellipse = new Ellipse(myrect.X, myrect.Y, myrect.Width, myrect.Height);
```

With the additional contrsutor this is more convenient.

Creating different versions of a constructor (or a method) is often referred to as 'syntactic sugar' as it sweetens a coders life.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's Take Your questions it self. It explains many things as you have taken it from book but in real world you have to think for your self.

1. :this(new RectangleF(x, y, width, height))
   Above line is used to call another constructor and also called constructor. When you do that constructor with matching signature called first. It means what ever value you have assign to any of class variable in that constructor are assign then your constructor being get called. So in current constructor if you want to perform any additional logic that is not possible to perform in base constructor then you can do that.
2. Code Reuse is main concern over here.  Now Why ? 
   Question say that If Width and Height are less then zero then you have to throw exception. Now you have created two constructor for your class as you want user of your class can either pass Ecplice setting as x,y,width,height format or rectangle format.

   - One way to do that is you write width and height login both place which is not good.
   - Second issue is that if you have use first constructor then it pass value as rectangle and second as x,y,width,height and if you don't store this value in single place then there problem later on in the code that which constructor is being called. Because if you have called first one then all logic based on second one x,y,width,height will not work and if you have called second one then logic related to Rectangle not work. So you might have to store extra bit of information then which constructor is being called, which is not good in this case as RectangleF will store same value.